# Alternate **kwargs for class __init__ function

Tags: python, object-oriented, classes

I want to set up a Python class so that it can be constructed with one set of parameters or another. I'm trying to mimic C++ function templates. I tried alternate constructors. In the actual code I'm working on I have subclasses that are also going to have alternate argument sets. Alternate constructors got real messy. Parsing through various instances of **kwargs was much easier.

I've written the code below but feel that it can be done much more efficiently. Any comments would be appreciated.

(If there's already a post that deals with this please let me know.)

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        expected_params = {'sentence', 'word1', 'word2'}

        self.sentence = ''

        # Check if the number of arguments matches the expected number of parameters
        if len(args)== 1:
            if len(kwargs) != 0:
                raise ValueError("You can't pass both positional arguments and named arguments.")
            if not(isinstance(args[0], str)):
                raise ValueError("Arguments must be strings")

            self.sentence = args[0]

        else:

            if not set(kwargs).issubset(expected_params):
                raise ValueError(f"Invalid arguments passed: {set(kwargs)-expected_params}.")

            if 'sentence' in kwargs:
                if {'word1', 'word2'}.intersection(set(kwargs)):
                    raise ValueError("You can only specify a sentence or words, not both.")

                if not(isinstance(kwargs['sentence'], str)):
                    raise ValueError("Arguments must be strings")

                self.sentence = kwargs['sentence']

            if 'word1' in kwargs:
                if not(isinstance(kwargs['word1'], str)):
                    raise ValueError("Arguments must be strings")

                self.sentence = kwargs['word1']

            if 'word2' in kwargs:
                if 'word1' not in kwargs:
                    raise ValueError("You have to specify word1 if you provide word2.")
                if not(isinstance(kwargs['word2'], str)):
                    raise ValueError("Arguments must be strings")

                self.sentence += kwargs['word2']
```

Comment: This is likely to be closed as hypothetical/stub code, as there's no usage of the class and the class has a placeholder name. If you show the real class as well as context around how it's used it may be able to stay on-topic.

Comment: OK. The real class is over 1,000 lines long. I created an excerpt to keep it simpler.

Comment: i did not understand the C++ comment. C++ templates enable duck-typing which is already built into python. Did you mean overloading instead?

Comment: Yes, I think so. There's a feature in C++ where you can define different versions of a function that differ in the arguments provided. The code knows which function to invoke depending on the arguments passed. I'm looking to do something similar in Python using kwargs.

Comment: Ah, yes it is called overloading there is a package called multipledispatch. Which lets you do C++ style overloading in Python. That way you don't have to do the `instance` checks.

Answer (score 5):

> I'm trying to mimic C++ function templates.

I certainly hope not. Ajinkya Kamat is correct to say that what you're looking for is overloading, and - for constructors or regular functions - Python does not support it directly.

> I tried alternate constructors.

Did you? Because this can mean a few things. It's not possible to define multiple `__init__` functions on one class, but there are workarounds.

> Parsing through various instances of `**kwargs` was much easier.

I somewhat doubt that it will be easier on you or your users, when compared to the structured approaches. `**kwargs` abuse is a plague on Python. For a particularly dire instance, take a look at [pandas.read_fwf](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_fwf.html). I challenge you to gain *any insight* on what those kwargs are able to accept without debugging the library itself.

So:

- Don't use `**kwargs`
- Add typehints
- Write `@classmethod` pseudoconstructors
- Make your class immutable

This can look like:

```py
from typing import NamedTuple


class MyClass(NamedTuple):
    sentence: str
    
    @classmethod
    def from_sentence(cls, sentence: str) -> 'MyClass':
        return cls(sentence)
    
    @classmethod
    def from_words(cls, *words: str) -> 'MyClass':
        return cls(' '.join(words))
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your comments. I followed them and am very happy with how my code turned out.

Answer (score 3):

I am assuming that by alternate constructors, you mean `classmethod`s like `from_words` and `from_sentence`. I am also assuming that you want to use `super().__init__()` from your subclass and that's why you do not prefer `classmethods`.

Using the number of keyword arguments or using `isinstance()` to change behavior can lead to code that mixes the business logic with language quirks. This can lead to difficult-to-read code. I suggest you take a look at techniques to do overloading. One such technique is to use a package like `multipledispatch`. This is how a rewrite of your code will look with `multipledispatch`.

```
from multipledispatch import dispatch

class MyClass:
    
    @dispatch(str)
    def __init__(self, sentence):
        self.sentence =  sentence

    @dispatch(str, str)
    def __init__(self, word1, word2):
        self.sentence = word1 + word2
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this comment. I learned something that I might use in the future.